# Type in gedit using xdotool in a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gedit, xdotool

I want to type a character in a shell and have `xdotool` send that character's signal to gedit, so that character will be typed in gedit.

I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit -s &
GEDPID=$!
sleep 2s
GEDWINID=`xdotool search --pid $GEDPID | tail -1`
echo "press any keys"
read i
xdotool windowactivate --sync $GEDWINID key --clearmodifiers --delay 100 "$i" && wmctrl -a Terminal
```

Everything works well except that the script waits for <kbd>enter</kbd> to send a keyboard signal to gedit.

So I've changed `read i` to `read -n1 i`, to make the script do its job without enter.

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit -s &
GEDPID=$!
sleep 2s
GEDWINID=`xdotool search --pid $GEDPID | tail -1`
echo "press any keys"
read -n1 i
xdotool windowactivate --sync $GEDWINID key --clearmodifiers --delay 100 "$i" && wmctrl -a Terminal
```

But it doesn't type any characters in gedit!

And here is the question, what is the second script's issue? What's difference between `read i` and `read -n1 i` that causes this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `xdotool key Return` at the end of your first script?

Comment: @Ravexina thanks for your reply.
yes I've try that before , but the `read` command needs to enter has been pressed so that doesn't work for me ...

Comment: @ali When I run your 2nd script `gedit -s` starts Gedit and its window becomes focused. If I activate Terminal window manually and type any character, it properly gets transferred into Gedit window. `-n1` option causes `read` to return after 1 character was read. Check `help read`, as it is an integrated Bash function. Also `wmctrl -a Terminal` isn't a good way to return focus to terminal, because several terminals can be opened in the same time.

Comment: @whtyger Thanks for you reply. But what is yours suggestion to do this pupose? What can I use instead of ‘read n1‘

Comment: @ali Check my answer.

Comment: This might be a silly question - why?

Comment: @Tim I want to use this script in my project So your answers can helpful, thanks

Comment: @ali76 I might be able to offer an alternative if I know why you need to automatically type into gedit from a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate this issue. While I don't know why there's a difference between `read` and `read -n1`, adding a simple delay before the key made it work. My guess is that there isn't enough time after the window switches for it to register the keypress.

```
#!/bin/bash
gedit -s &
GEDPID=$!
sleep 2s
GEDWINID=`xdotool search --pid $GEDPID | tail -1`
echo "press any keys"
read -n1 i
xdotool sleep 0.1 windowactivate --sync $GEDWINID key --clearmodifiers --delay 100 "$i" && wmctrl -a Terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your original script so it properly gets window ID of your current terminal and switches focus between the Terminal and Gedit windows. This script uses infinite loop, so all keystrokes being print in Terminal window are transferred into Gedit. Cancel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
#!/bin/bash

WIDGTERM=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
gedit -s 2> /dev/null &
sleep 2s
WIDGEDIT=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
xdotool windowactivate $WIDGTERM
echo "Press any keys"
while true
do
  read -n1 i
  xdotool windowactivate --sync $WIDGEDIT key --clearmodifiers "$i"
  sleep .5
  xdotool windowactivate --sync $WIDGTERM
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not work (the characters not transfered one by one / not things was transfered) I guess that it's because of `read -n1 i`. Whats your guess ?

Comment: @ali That's strange. Tested on two systems - Precise 32-bit and Xenial 64-bit - all works fine. When character is typed in Terminal, window is switched to Gedit, character is printed there and then focus is switched back to Terminal. Do you observe windows switching when you type characters in Terminal? Try increasing delay between the switching (use `1s` instead of `.5` in `sleep` command in the loop).

Comment: Yes windows are switched between Terminal and Gedit but character not printed!

Comment: I use `1s` instead of `.5` and same result occurred and any character was printed.  but when I use `read i` instead of `read -n1 i` it works well !

Comment: @ali `read i` waits indefinitely until you press "Enter" and then puts all printed characters into `$i` variable. `read -n1 i` waits for only one symbol and puts it into `$i` variable automatically. If you use `-n3` it will wait for 3 symbols and so on. That's the difference between the invocations of `read`. Check `help read`, all the options can be found there.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't know why `read -n1 i` not works in this script

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 17.04 64bit

Comment: @ali Try `read -N 1 i` instead of `-n` option. If it won't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it doesn't work again